# how does react <Link> works? Absolute path in <Link>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

fist of all i am sorry if the question seems dumb but i am still learning react and html. 
So the thing is that i have a Button tag in my react code which provides me with some logic about going in a specific link i provide. My Button.js ultimately is a Link which is taking me to a link i provide:

```js
    <Link
      className={[
        'button',
        `button--${props.design}`,
        `button--${props.mode}`
      ].join(' ')}
      to={props.link}
    >
```

when i am in the route "/" and i call the Button tag with a link to a postId i go to "/:postId" page which is the post page i have in my backend

```js
<Button mode="flat" link={this.props.id}>
```

but when i am in the route "/profile/" and i am executing the Button i am going to route "/profile/:postId" and this is not my post page in my backend so nothing happens and i cant see the post page.

How can i go to "/:postId" even when i am in the "/profile/" route?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is related to relative links. Try updating your use of `Button` to preface your "link" with a forward slash:

```
<Button mode="flat" link=`/${this.props.id}`>
```

Comment: yeah it was indeed an issue with relative paths. but it didn't work changing it to the <Button> as you mention. i had to change it on the <Link>. the thing is that it treats `to={props.link}` attribute as an object and in this case it adds that to the current url. I had to pass a string in order to get it as an absolute path like this `<Link
      className={[
        'button',
        `button--${props.design}`,
        `button--${props.mode}`
      ].join(' ')}
      to={`/${props.link}`}
    >`

Comment: yeah a lot of ` characters f***d up the way my comment is showing. i guess you understand what i changed though. i will also post it as an answer so everyone can read it more clear

Answer (score 0):

In the < Link > it treats `to={props.link}` as an object and it does not create an absolute path. I had to change it like this

```js
    <Link
      className={[
        'button',
        `button--${props.design}`,
        `button--${props.mode}`
      ].join(' ')}
      to={`/${props.link}`}
    >
```

in order to treat it like a string which represents an absolute path